sequence of integral of a function
Let $a_n=\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{n}\frac{log(2+x)}{\sqrt{1+x}}dx$ then i want to show $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\rightarrow 0$.
i assume $b_n=\int_{n-1}^{n}\frac{log(2+x)}{\sqrt{1+x}}dx$ and $a_n=\frac{b_1+b_2\cdots +b_n}{n},$
then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n= \lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$ but then unable to compute $b_n$

$0<b_n<\frac {log (2+n)} {\sqrt {n}} \to 0$.

thanks alot i am so dumb only using inequalities instead of monotonicity i always comes close and mess up.

i am thinking about mean value theorem

Another method you can try is
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_{0}^{n}\frac{log(2+x)}{\sqrt{1+x}}dx}{n}
$$
Apply L'Hôpital's rule and Leibniz integral rule
We get $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(2+x)}{\sqrt{1+x}}=0$$

ya i forgot to add tag, limit without lhoptial , still its good to have this ans

oh ill just leave this up then cheers

no bro thats just appreciated +1
